# WebDriver - How to do drag and drop operation

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to do drag an element and drop on another element using WebDriver.
Tried like this. Seems to be correct logically, but does not seem to work.

(Ensured that drag and drop elements are correctly identified)

```
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();  
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp");

        WebElement drag = driver.findElement(By.id("drag1"));
        WebElement drop = driver.findElement(By.id("div2"));

        Actions action = new Actions(driver);

        action.dragAndDrop(drag, drop)
                .build()
                .perform();

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);  
        driver.quit();
```

Tried like this as well - no luck

```
        action.clickAndHold(drag)
                .moveToElement(drop)
                .release(drop)
                .build()
                .perform();
```

Am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Its a bug currently in webdriver in case of HTML5 drag and drop. For a workaround you can visit http://elementalselenium.com/tips/39-drag-and-drop site. Thanks

Comment: hi someone jas already logged a bug regarding this in selenium dev forum.   https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6315  lets wait to get it fixed